# Where can I find replacement stops for a shower faucet?

Tags: plumbing, shower, leak, replacement

I've looked *everywhere* locally for a replacement shower stop and cannot find the right now. This is from an old shower (about 20 years). I've attached photos that show the size on top of a ruler.

The wide part is about 7/8" diameter, the narrow part is about 5/8". The hole in the center is about 3/8" diameter. It's plastic, and about 1/8" in thickness.

Any ideas? I'd really rather not replace the entire cartridge for this one small part, since that would involve taking out tile, etc....

Thanks!!!

-h

[image: wide view]
[image: narrow view]

Comment: We need clues as to the manufacturer. Is there any maker's mark or name on the handle/knob or trim? Could you post a picture of the handle/knob and trim?

Comment: Repair the break with a vinyl-type adhesive: http://www.amazon.com/Amazing-GOOP-Plumbing-3-7oz-Adhesive/dp/B0016L0NTU/ref=sr_1_3?ie=UTF8&qid=1451771151&sr=8-3&keywords=plumbers+goop

Answer (score 1):

I'd say Screw It. That is, I haven't found any glue to be permanent & have had fantastic results only with screws. Screws for plastic that are coarse threaded are the best. Find tiny screws, coarse or fine thread, & pre-drill homes for them slightly tinier than the screw's threads, you'll need a precision or eyeglasses screw driver to seat them...I'd do both the crack & the split. And, still crazy glue it just before your screws re-join everything for a good as or better than new stop. Then, you'll also have a solid part to even make a joint compound mold & make your own new stop...it's just plastic & any PVC or ABS would do. I'd even bet you could quite easily make your own out of a thick metal washer with some very careful jig-sawing & drilling, it ain't gotta be pretty it just needs to last.